# Android передача ссылки на объект между Activity

Tags: android, bluetooth

Создал Bluetooth сервер и клиент в MainActivity. Есть 2 связанных BluetoothSocket Как передать ссылку на объект в другое Activity, что бы эти объекты остались "живы"? Или какой лучше способ поддерживать работа Bluetooth соединения?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Один из вариантов, создать класс, наследник от `Application` и хранить ссылку в нём. Класс `Application` является синглтоном внутри одного процесса приложения, а значит вы всегда будете получать ссылку на один и тот же объект.

```
public class App extends Application {
    private BluetoothSocket btSocket;

    public BluetoothSocket getBtSocket() {
        return btSocket;
    }

    public void setBtSocket(BluetoothSocket btSocket) {
        this.btSocket = btSocket;
    }
}
```

И затем из активити можно устанавливать и получать данный объект:

```
// Установка в одной активити
((App) getApplication()).setBtSocket(someBtSocketObject); 

// Получение в другой активити
BluetoothSocket someBtSocketObject = ((App) getApplication()).getBtSocket();
```

И не забудьте прописать класс `App` в манифесте:

```
<application
    android:name="your.package.name.App"
    ...
```